# Transform data by time & Class

Tags: pandas, datetime, grouping, transform

I have a dataframe nf as following:

```
         DateTime       Class   Count
0   2017-10-01 00:00:00 1       0
1   2017-10-01 00:00:00 2       240
2   2017-10-01 00:00:00 3       17
3   2017-10-01 00:00:00 4       0
4   2017-10-01 00:00:00 5       1
5   2017-10-01 00:00:00 6       0
6   2017-10-01 00:00:00 7       0
7   2017-10-01 00:00:00 8       0
8   2017-10-01 00:00:00 9       0
9   2017-10-01 00:00:00 10      0
10  2017-10-01 00:00:00 11      0
11  2017-10-01 00:00:00 12      0
12  2017-10-01 00:00:00 13      0
13  2017-10-01 00:00:00 14      0
14  2017-10-01 00:00:00 15      0
..............................
30  2017-10-01 01:00:00 1       0
31  2017-10-01 01:00:00 2       209
32  2017-10-01 01:00:00 3       14
33  2017-10-01 01:00:00 4       0
34  2017-10-01 01:00:00 5       4
35  2017-10-01 01:00:00 6       0
36  2017-10-01 01:00:00 7       0
37  2017-10-01 01:00:00 8       0
38  2017-10-01 01:00:00 9       0
39  2017-10-01 01:00:00 10      0
40  2017-10-01 01:00:00 11      0
41  2017-10-01 01:00:00 12      0
42  2017-10-01 01:00:00 13      0
43  2017-10-01 01:00:00 14      0
44  2017-10-01 01:00:00 15      0
....... and so on
```

There are total 15 classes and counts for each class for each hour

I want to transform the data into columnwise on a per hour for each count basis as follows

Output req

```
DateTime              Class1  Class2 Class3 Class4.........Class15
2017-10-01 00:00:00    0      240     17     0    .........  0 
2017-10-01 00:01:00    0      209     14     0    .........  0
....
and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas to read the data into a pd.Dataframe(), select the counts for each class by slicing the dataframe with conditions and concate the data after that by using the datetime as index:

```
import pandas as pd

# create dataframe from file
df = pd.read_csv('fname')
# or from numpy array
df = pd.Dataframe(data=np_array, columns=['DateTime', 'Class', 'Count'])

# select the counts for each class
df_c1 = df[df.Class == 1]
df_c2 = df[df.Class == 2] 
df_c3 = df[df.Class == 3]
df_c4 = df[df.Class == 4]

df_new = pd.Dataframe()
df_new['DateTime'] = df_c1['DateTime']
df_new['Class1'] = df_c1['Count']
df_new['Class2'] = df_c2['Count']
df_new['Class3'] = df_c3['Count']
df_new['Class4'] = df_c4['Count']
```

The code example is really dirty and I'm probably missing alot, but maybe it gives you an inspiration. I would also recommend you to check the pandas documentation for [concat()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) and [Dataframe()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dataframe)

I'm going to review and refactor my example code tomorrow, in case the problem is not solved already. Meanwhile you could fix the layout of the data in your question it's not readable.

Comment: I am sorry but the solution provided isn't working and correct

Answer (score 0):

Try `pivot_table`:

```
(df.pivot_table(index='DateTime',columns='Class',
               values='Count',
               aggfunc='sum')
  .add_prefix('Class_'))
```

Comment: @Nik If this answer helped you would you consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=votes#tab-top)